# Replacement for "this means that ..."

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I often write texts where I offer an explanation of some issue followed by a paragraph discussing the implications for the reader. I generally start those paragraphs with "this means":

> [Longer explanation that cutting yourself in the foot hurts]
>
> This means that you need to be careful and wear safety clothing when operating chain saws. There are several types of safety features ...

I don't like the "this means that" phrase very much, but I'm not a native speaker, so maybe it is fine? If not, what alternatives should I use?

Comment: Therefore, Accordingly, Consequently, and so on...

Comment: There are innumerable alternatives. If you want writing advice, you should visit [writers.se] instead.

Comment: Looking over the content at Writers.SE, the question seems to fit here a lot more than it does over there. I  thought the "phrase requests" tag fit pretty well: "This tag is for questions seeking a phrase that fits a meaning"

Comment: Hi, Christian, your question could generate primarily-opinion-based answers or is too broad to be answered. That seems to be the problem. Can you try to narrow it down to some of your best candidates? This rule may apply to your question. **Writing advice (see [Writers.SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com/) instead) or critique requests are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified**.

Comment: @Rathony: Thanks for your feedback. I updated the question, I hope it fits better on ELL now. I'm specifically concerned about the "this means that" part, as I consider it inelegant. I'm looking for alternative phrases.

Comment: It is EL&U here. Let's wait until others respond to your question.:-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. We could not process all the customer requests yesterday. The problem was due to not having sufficient computing power. Fortunately, the production supervisor allowed us to use their idling systems to process them, but at 2 am.

   **We realise that** we need to improve our processing capacity, and buy a bigger and more powerful machine.

   **We need to realise** that sufficient computing resources is essential to keeping our customer base, as well as being able to collect payments from them in time.
2. The garbage cans in the office kitchen are overflowing again. That is a bio-hazard. We have more employees now, and the cans fill up quicker.

   **The implication is** our needing to pay for daily janitorial service, rather than weekly.
3. The prisoners at the death row are getting obese. Yesterday prisoner #A7825 had a massive heart attack and died rather immediately.

   **Consequently**, hardline senator Joseph A Smith called to inquire the state's legal dept if that could be our alternative method of execution, in view of our German suppliers refusing to supply us with anymore death row chemicals.
4. The cow jumped over the moon again. This time she managed to jump three times to get across to the bulls.

   **The incidents show that** we need to raise the height of the moon another foot. Otherwise, we run the risk of the cows being impregnated by the wrong bull.
5. Dear John, you how I hate to write. But, I must let you know tonight that my love for you has died. Because you have gotten into too many a fight. Now I am taking flight. I will take the dog and you the kite.

   **It should dawn upon** you, you need to avoid getting into brawls every chance you get if and when you find a new girlfriend.
6. There isn't a customer base anymore in our upper east location. That neighbourhood is desolate due to the violent occurrences of crime. We had been robbed and burglarized too many times.

   We should **tie up** this **loose end** in our strategy, and close down that location so that we could open up another shop in the more affluent west side of the city, in order to survive as a business.
7. The HIV rate among the trade is rising again.

   **Need** we **remind** ya'll that you should absolutely refuse a customer unless he uses a condom?

   **The truth of the situation** is that, to stay alive, you need to be vigilant about safety when servicing your customers.

   **It is rather obvious that** safety is of utmost importance in the trade.
8. The terrorists are complete in their desire to destroy us. Yesterday, we caught a breach, where otherwise 500 people would have been dead this morning.

   **Make no mistake**, that we need the NSA fully empowered to given to invade the privacy of anyone whenever they deem necessary.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that what you're referring to is a sentence transitional phrase. In this particular case, you want to add clarification to what is previously stated. If you're tired of using, `this means`, then there are plenty of other words you can choose from.

For example:

- `In other words, you need to be careful and wear safety clothing when operating chain saws.`
- `That is, you need to be careful and wear safety clothing when operating chain saws.`

I hope this helps.