# Alternatives to "this means that.."?

Tags: word-choice

**What are some alternatives to "this means..." or "this means that..."?** I'm currently writing an essay on how the Aztecs were a great world civilisation, not barbarians. An example that I'm giving is that education was compulsory for all children, regardless of class/rank in hierarchy. I've already used the phrase, "this means that..." multiple times, and I'm looking for a few alternatives.

Comment: Welcome to Writing SE. I've voted to close this question, as it belongs on English SE - you're asking for alternate words/synonyms which is beyond the scope of this particular site, but right up the alley of English SE.

Comment: "Consequently", "Therefore", "Thus", "As such", "As a result", "Hence", "Accordingly", "And so", "For this reason" etc. etc. ....

Answer (score 2):

Therefore, ergo and thus could be the word you're looking for.

Comment: Additional options: "Thus it follows", "Hence", "from this we see", "meaning", "[consequently](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/consequently)", etc...

Comment: Yeah, there's many options here

Answer (score 1):

There are some really good options available in this question here:
[replacement-for-this-means-that on english.stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297073/replacement-for-this-means-that)

Taking a look through the whole site here might also give a side benefit of expanding your overall knowledge & use of the English language, which is generally helpful to those of us who are cursed to be writers and are trying to do so in the language aberration that is English...